# Rich Push messages Urban Airship

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com, richpush

I am having troubles to get Rich Push messages working with Urban Airship for Android. I tried to implement by myself looking at the tutorials, but after many tries i decided to test first the sample app from the github: https://github.com/urbanairship/android-samples/tree/master/RichPushSample

The problem is that is not working as i was expecting to work. I send the Rich Push messages from their testing website, and if i check the inbox i can see the new messages (and the old ones of course), but i never get a notification for those pushes.I didn't change anything in the code (neither in the AndroidManifest.xml).

Normal pushes are working fine, and debugging i can see how the RichNotificationBuilder creates the notification for normal pushes, and when tapped, the PushReceiver handles the intent. However for the Rich Push messages i never get a notification (thus i never receive intent in PushReceiver).

All the listeners they provide for rich push messages RichPushInbox.Listener, RichPushManager.Listener are only receiving when manually triggering inbox updates and so on (never when sending rich push from website)

Also tried sending them an email to their support email, but no answer.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: have you registered provider and receiver in your menifest.

Comment: @DeepakPanwar yeah, as i said i didn't change anything in the manifest, all of that is included. Is weird because normal pushes are coming without any issues. Have you ever got this working? I mean, getting notifications from rich push, not only updating the inbox.

Comment: Yes i had done this before. Cloud to device works perfect.  Please answer some questions. Have you changed package name ?  Their package name is com.urbanairship.richpush.sample     and in class RichPushapplication you can see for message id MESSAGE_ID_RECEIVED_KEY = "com.urbanairship.richpush.sample.MESSAGE_ID_RECEIVED";    and in rich notication builder it is receving messages for id PushReceiver.EXTRA_MESSAGE_ID_KEY.          Just check some parameters and it would work fine.

Comment: finally got it to work, but only when using the Message composer and creating a new Message Center with the APID. If i try to send it with the Test Rich Push using the User value, is never working. Really strange, because normal pushes works with its Test section.... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @nsL i am facing the same issue as u have.successfully run demo application for rich push sample.
When i send notification using userid i didnt get any notification but get message in inbox.
My question is how to get rich push notification ?
And when i send notification using APID from sample push i get notification in same app.

Comment: @Kutbi you are using the Test Rich Push section? i never got it to work that way, as you i get the message inbox, but never the notification. If you want to get the notification try in this section Messages -> Messages Overview -> +Message. And there in Destination choose Message Center -> +Rich Page. There you have some templates. After that you have to choose if you send it to all devices or to a specific APID, and if you send it inmediately o scheduled. With this i finally got it to work. Hope it helps!

Comment: I had the same situation where rich messages were not arriving, even though non-rich messages were.

After 10 minutes of investigation, suddenly the two rich messages I had sent showed up on my device. I'm pretty sure they were queued up somewhere in the back-end, because my device had good connectivity during the wait.